# print mysql command prompt "\G" outputs in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I can output `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G;` in text file from command line. Also any query using mysqli_fetch_array() or [mysqli_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

The below is also possible as we have the column names (Type, Name, Status)

```
mysql> SHOW ENGINE PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA STATUS;
+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Type               | Name                                                        | Status   |
+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| performance_schema | events_waits_current.size                                   | 186      |
```

Now, I want to print the complete output of  `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G;` in web browser through php.

I have gone through [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and  [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) but cant really get that into work. Please help

Expected output in web browser

```
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 11271
Purge done for trx's n:o < 11271 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 36
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 421919568688976, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
```

Also, I dont want to create a file and read it from php

```
echo file_get_contents( "innodb_status.php" );
```

Comment: So all `\G` does is display output vertically. All you need to do is fetch the result of the query (without `\G`) and just output the `Status` field inside a `<pre>` tag.

Comment: Yes that is what I want. thanks for suggestion. You mean this will work `echo "<pre>"; print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query("SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS"))); echo "</pre>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using var_export worked but it contains array keys.

```
echo "<pre>";
var_export(array_values($innodb_row));
echo "</pre>";
```

The below worked perfectly and given the desired output

```
$remoteconnect = mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","","port","");
    if (!$remoteconnect)
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    else {

    $innodb = "show engine innodb status" ;    
    $innodb_result = mysqli_query($remoteconnect,$innodb);

    if (!$innodb_result) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($remoteconnect));
        exit();          }

    while($innodb_row = mysqli_fetch_array($innodb_result)) {
    echo "<pre>".$innodb_row[0].$innodb_row[1].$innodb_row[2]."</pre>";
    }

         }
    mysqli_close($remoteconnect);
```